# Entity Framework 6 unintended auto loading navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am having an issue where a navigation property on my entity is being automatically loaded.

I have a class View that has the following properties

```
public string ParentUUID{get;set;}
public View Parent{get;set;}
public List<View> Children{get;set;}
```

I then have in my modelbuilder

```
this.HasOptional(it => it.Parent).WithMany(it => it.Children).HasForeignKey(it => it.ParentUUID);
```

When I call

```
db.Views.ToList();
```

it is loading the parent and children of each view without me specifically including it - I understand that this probably has something to do with the fact that the views are there so already in the set so they get attached - but I need to stop this from happening as I need to serialize the view without the circular references

any pointers would be greatly welcomed.

cheers,

Comment: As an aside, if your only motivation for this is to avoid serializing a circular reference, with JSON.NET you can explicitly set an option to ignore circular references during serialization.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware of the recursionlimit property - I'll take a look at that as I think that will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your navigation properties as `virtual` to get lazy-loading.

```
public string ParentUUID{get;set;}
public virtual View Parent{get;set;}
public virtual List<View> Children{get;set;}
```

When EF hydrates the data, it's using a proxy that is derived from your class which effects the lazy-load of the navigation properties upon first access.  Note that you have to perform that access within the scope of the DbContext used to initially load the entities, though.  If that DbContext is closed, you'll get an exception.

**EDIT**

IF you don't want them to load at all, then keep them unmapped by using the `NotMappedAttribute` on the properties themselves:

```
public string ParentUUID{get;set;}

[NotMapped]
public View Parent{get;set;}

[NotMapped]
public List<View> Children{get;set;}
```

...or by using the `Ignore()` fluent model-configuration method:

```
...
this.Ignore(e => e.Parent);
this.Ignore(e => e.Children);
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, but reverse issue - I've not included virtual because I don't want the lazy loading, I'm still getting lazy loading on the object - I've even tried specifically setting lazy loading to off but they still get loaded.

Comment: If you don't effect lazy-loading using `virtual`, the navigation properties will be hydrated--fetched--immediately on the initial load. If they weren't loaded at either point, when would you want them to load?

Comment: That's kind of the point - because of what I was trying to achieve I didn't want them loading at all.